# Using python-serial in Raspbian Jessie in virtualenv

Tags: virtualenv, python-3.4, raspbian

I am trying to use python-serial in Raspbian Jessie on RPi2 with virtualenv. I am working with OpenCV 3.0.0 and Python 3.4.2 but when I am trying to "import serial" in python 3 in virtualenv I got an error that module doesn't exist. But when I run python2 in virtualenv I can use virtualenv normally.

I have tried to install python-serial/python3-serial with apt-get install or with pip/pip3 install pyserial but nothing happens (of course in virtualenv). Where I have mad mistake?

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue. Any solutions yet??

Answer (score 1):

try below command,

```
python3.4 -m pip install pyserial
```

ref. https://docs.python.org/3.4/installing/

Comment: I have already mentioned the command to install the pyserial for python3.4  in a virtual environment and link of the page.